# Running a specific code block in case Option result is None with specific guarding function

Tags: scala

Is there a more elegant, Scala way, to have a specific code executed only in None match, for a specific if guard? For example:

```
Option(someExternalCall(data)) match {
      case Some(_) => Some(_)
      case None if checkSomething() => throw new RuntimeException
      case None => None
    }
```

**Editing**

As suggested in an answer here, the code:

```
  Option(someExternalCall(data))
    .getOrElse(
      if(checkSomething()) throw new RuntimeException 
      else None
    )
```

Return a `Serializable` result, while in my initial code it's `Option[Type]` and that's what I would like to have as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify it to

```
Option(someExternalCall(data)) match {
  case None if checkSomething() => throw new RuntimeException
  case v => v
}
```

or perhaps utilise `tap` for the side-effect

```
import scala.util.chaining._

someExternalCall(data)
  .tap { v => if (v.isEmpty && checkSomething()) throw new RuntimeException }
```

however I would suggested instead refactoring such that `someExternalCall` already returns an `Option`, perhaps something like

```
/**
 * @throws java.lang.RuntimeException
 */
def someExternalCall(data: Foo): Option[Bar] = ???
```

Note that `Option(someExternalCall(data))` returns `None` if `someExternalCall(data)` returns `null` which is sometimes the case with Java APIs, but if it is not returning `null` you should probably just return `Some` and `None` directly

```
scala> def f(): String = null
def f(): String

scala> Option(f())
val res0: Option[String] = None
```